# Edit text inside message sent by telegram bot without sending another message

Tags: python, telegram

I have a telegram bot and I want it to delete the message and put another message in the same place.

I'm sending the message this way:

```
updater.message.reply_text('please wait...')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified which API you are using I'll give you an example with 
these: [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

The command to use is:

```
botName.edit_message_text(new_text, chat_id, message_id)
```

Below I give you a small example of how to implement it.

If you uncomment the `print() you will see that every message sent and received gives a lot of information about the bot.

And you can take advantage of those to do whatever you like.

The basic example is the following:

```
import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'YOUR API TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    var_data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hi there, I am EchoBot.")
    #print(var_data)
    bot.edit_message_text("Hi, " + str(message.from_user.first_name), var_data.chat.id, var_data.message_id)

bot.polling()
```